# concurrently"npm run server"" is not recognized as an internal or external command. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

> merncrud@1.0.0 dev
> concurrently"npm run server"" npm run client"

'concurrently"npm run server"" npm run client"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.ile.

After I install concurrently.
I typed "npm run dev".
In that time I faced this issue.
Anyone can help me. Thank you

Comment: you forgot the space after `concurrently`

Comment: share your package.json and a demo of your js